# How to compare similar data

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert the data to PL-SQL.

But I need to check whether the table has similar Data.

If the table check has similar information, it cannot be added

exanple:

Insert Data : ABCD or ABCE

Table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN3aH.png)

The Tabel Device has ABC,so it cannot be added.

How can I write this program?

Comment: Please: 1) Describe what you consider *similar*, bu what criteria and with what threshold of similarity. 2) Provide sample data in **text** format. 3) Provide the desired result you need to have. 4). Show what did you try so far and why it was not sufficient (any errors in text format or description what is wrong in the result).

Answer (score 0):

You can use instr in plsql

example:

```
declare 
x number;
begin
for i in (select distinct value from table)
loop

select count(1) into x 
from table2
where instr(Device, i.value) > 0;

if (x = 0) then
   insert into table2(Device) values(i.value);
end if;

commit;
end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar or the same data? That makes a huge difference. Because if you don't want the same data in your columns, you can just make the column unique. But if you want to check for similar data, welp, that's kind of hard to implement, hard to understand, and that just outright kills your performance...But if you still want to go that way, you can check out [Jaro-Winkler Algorithm](https://medium.com/@appaloosastore/string-similarity-algorithms-compared-3f7b4d12f0ff)

Answer (score 0):

Isi already mentioned the algorithm; here's an example of what you might be looking for.

Current table contents:

```
SQL> select * from test;

COL
-----
ABC
ABD
ABR
```

Here's how *similar* current values are to certain strings (ABCD, FDGH) you'd want to insert:

```
SQL> select t.col,
  2         utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity('ABCD', t.col) sim_abcd,
  3         utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity('FDGH', t.col) sim_fdgh
  4  from test t;

COL     SIM_ABCD   SIM_FDGH
----- ---------- ----------
ABC           94          0
ABD           93         52
ABR           77          0
```

Now, it is up to you to decide which value will represent a *limit* and either insert a value into that table or not. Let's presume it is 90%. Then you'd

```
SQL> insert into test (col)
  2    select '&&par_insert'
  3    from dual
  4    where 90 > (select max(utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity('&&par_insert', a.col))
  5                from test a
  6               );
Enter value for par_insert: ABCD

0 rows created.

SQL>
```

Right; ABCD is similar to any of current values more than 90% and wasn't inserted.

How about FDGH?

```
SQL> undefine par_insert
SQL> /
Enter value for par_insert: FDGH

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

COL
-----
ABC
ABD
ABR
FDGH

SQL>
```

Yes, it was inserted.